# Convert urllib2 output to a list python

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, urllib2

I want to convert the string that I get from urllib2 into an array or list of words. I am doing a school project and am stuck on this part. Any suggestions? My code is below.

```
import urllib.request

url = input("Please enter a URL: ")

f=urllib.request.urlopen(url)

print(f.read())
```

I want all the words in the html string that urllib generates to be parsed and have each word be placed in its own index in either an array or a list.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/'>

Comment: List of words? Did you try splitting output by space: `str.split()`?